# Is is possible to share data between different Modules components in angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I have tried sharing data between modules between their components but unable to do so, I tried to go through services approach but thought that if you can cut an apple through knife then why use sword for it.

Comment: You have to import a service from both components and then reference the same variable.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you share snippet code too.

I think by this approach you can get data as you want. SharedData class needs only to be set in app.module.ts and import sharedService in any module where you want you use.

```js
// shared.module.ts

import ...
// create shared data
const sharedModule = new AdmobService(new AdMobFree(), new InAppPurchase()); 

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    //...,
    { provide: AdmobService, useValue: sharedModule }, 
  ]
})
export class sharedModule { }

// Module1
// module1.ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    sharedModule, // import shared module
  ],
})
export class Module1 { }


// Module 2
/// module2.ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    sharedModule, // import shared module
  ],
})
export class Module2 { }
```